# Is it possible to enumerate all the build variables supplied at queue time to a TFS vNext build?

Tags: azure-devops

I am providing a variable at queue time:

[image]

This variable is **not** defined amongst the build definition variables:

[image]

When the build runs the variable is exposed as `ABC` environment variable. So, if the build step knows to expect a variable `abc`, then it can get its value.

But what if the build step needs to enumerate all the variables passed at queue time? Aside from using a special naming convention, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a PowerShell task using a combination of the [Build-Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and [Builds-Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) APIs.  You can execute this as a step in the executing build.

```
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}"

$definitionParameters = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty variables

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}"

$buildParameters = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty parameters | 
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($parameter in $buildParameters) {

    $found = $definitionParameters | 
        Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
        Where-Object { $_ -eq $parameter}

    if (-not $found) {
        $parameter
    } 
}
```

So a build definition that has parameters A,B and a build that has parameters A,B,C - this would print C.

I mocked up the azuredevops URI, but tested this on a local tfs2018 instance.

Replace the `-UseDefaultCredentials` with either your token or the System Access token in a pipeline.